# java - JTextField wont show properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I'm working on a small java project and the end goal is a program that tells you how many days are in a specified month. My problem is only one of my textfields is showing up in the GUI! I have no idea why this is happening and have been looking around for a solution for about 2 hours. Please Help! p.s. I'm a novice programer, at least in java so this may be an obvious answer!

My code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "serial" })
public class Test extends JFrame {
  JTextField text;
  JTextField text2 = new JTextField("Enter Year", 40);
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JLabel label1;
  String Input1;
  String Input2;
  int month;
  int year;
  int numDays = 0;

  public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    text  = new JTextField("Enter month's #", 40);
    text2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,800));
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    getContentPane().add(text, "Center");
    getContentPane().add(text2, "Center");
    pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().setVisible(true);
  }
    class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     Input1 = text.getText();
     Input2 = text2.getText();
     month = Integer.parseInt(Input1);
     year = Integer.parseInt(Input2);
     math(month, year);
  }
 }
  public void math(int month, int year){
      switch (month) {
      case 1: case 3: case 5:
      case 7: case 8: case 10:
      case 12:
          numDays = 31;
          break;
      case 4: case 6:
      case 9: case 11:
          numDays = 30;
          break;
      case 2:
          if (((year % 4 == 0) && 
               !(year % 100 == 0))
               || (year % 400 == 0))
              numDays = 29;
          else
              numDays = 28;
          break;
      default:
          label1 = new JLabel("Invalid input...");
          getContentPane().add(label1, JLabel.BOTTOM);
          break;
  }
  label1 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(numDays));
  getContentPane().add(label1, JLabel.BOTTOM);
  }
}
```

I'm sure its probably something I just simply over looked and i hope their is a simple solution! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which only manages a single component at each of the 5 available positions, in this case, only the last component you have added

Depending on what you want to achieve will determine which layout manager you might use.

For example, you could use `GridBagLayout`

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        JTextField text;
        JTextField text2 = new JTextField("Enter Year", 40);
        JLabel label1;
        String Input1;
        String Input2;
        int month;
        int year;
        int numDays = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            text = new JTextField("Enter month's #", 40);
            text2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(text, gbc);
            add(text2, gbc);
        }

        class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Input1 = text.getText();
                Input2 = text2.getText();
                month = Integer.parseInt(Input1);
                year = Integer.parseInt(Input2);
                math(month, year);
            }
        }

        public void math(int month, int year) {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            switch (month) {
                case 1:
                case 3:
                case 5:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 10:
                case 12:
                    numDays = 31;
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 9:
                case 11:
                    numDays = 30;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (((year % 4 == 0)
                                    && !(year % 100 == 0))
                                    || (year % 400 == 0)) {
                        numDays = 29;
                    } else {
                        numDays = 28;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    label1 = new JLabel("Invalid input...");
                    add(label1, gbc);
                    break;
            }
            label1 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(numDays));
            add(label1, gbc);
        }

    }
}
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details.

Typically though, you make use of a number of layout managers, isolating your UI into workable units, focusing on the individual requirements of each section within their own container and then combining them through the use of other layout managers

Comment: Glad it could help. I can't stress enough that you have look at the links about the layout managers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both textfields are located at the center position. Mybe you wanted to add them to the panel. Change this:

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(text2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```